# How to set size of empty arrays python

Tags: python

I need to set the size of a bunch of different arrays.

I have made 25 empty arrays by doing arrays = [[] for k in range(n)]

now I need to set the size of each one starting at 2 and going to 2^25

so each arrays exponent should increase by one each time

for example, the first array is size 2 and then the second is 2^2 and then 2^3 and then 2^4 so on and so on until 2^25

Comment: As in the result should be [[[], [], [] ,[]], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]]...?  
For example, should it be an array of arrays of arrays where each array inside the first array should contain 2^n empty arrays?

Comment: Also note that 2^25 is 3.3 million

Comment: *"set size of empty arrays"*??? Empty means size is 0, otherwise it's not empty. Unclear what you want.

Answer (score -2):

This can be achieved by multiplying the inner lists by `2^(i+1)`, or in python, `2**(i+1)`.  You also need to add `[]` inside the list so that there is something to repeat.

The value to be inside the list is the first '[]' (inside another '[]')

```
result = [[[]]*(2**(i+1)) for i in range(25)]
```

Comment: This code has a serious problem.  Despite what you think, this code will only produce 26 lists, and all of them will contain references to the SAME list.  If you change `repeat`, that will change every one of the 4 million list entries.

Comment: @TimRoberts Why 4 million? It's about 67 million. The OP appears to want to consider them "empty", maybe in the sense of `numpy.empty`, i.e., considering the entries undefined and they won't ever read the initial value, then it's not a problem.

Comment: The edit didn't really fix an issue, but introduced a syntax error.